# Добавление новых строк в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

`WinForm`. Есть `DataGridView` не привязаный к `DataSource`.
Руками добавляю в него строку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему появляется внизу пустая строка со звездочкой?

Я так понимаю, это для добавления новой строки.
Но почему грид считает что это "живая" строка? В отладке её видно.
Как от нее избавиться и не потерять возможность добавления строк?

Answer (score 1):

За наличие этой строки отвечает свойство `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`. Избавиться от этой строки и не потерять возможность добавления строк можно путем установки значения этого свойства в `false` и реализовав добавление строк, например, при нажатии на кнопку. Про программное добавление строк можно почитать [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063770/how-to-add-a-new-row-to-datagridview-programmatically), а также [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread253216.html) и [тут](http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=198574) (первые ссылки в гугле).